# What's the recommended way to replace a bad GKE node instance?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Using `gcloud container clusters resize` I can easily scale up and down a cluster. However I find no way to target a specific compute instance vm for removal when resizing down.

Scenario: Our Compute Engine logs indicate that one instance suffers from failure to dismount a volume, from a Kubernetes pod that is since long gone. The cluster is appropriately sized, and the malfunctioning node serves containers properly but is on maximum CPU load.

Obviously I'd want a new Kubernetes node to be ready before I kill off the old one. Is it safe to simply resize up and then delete the instance using `gcloud compute`, or is there some container-aware way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However I find no way to target a specific compute instance vm for removal when resizing down.

There isn't a way to specify which VM to remove using the GKE API, but you can use the managed instance groups API to [delete individual instances from the group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/#delete_from_group) (this will shrink your number of nodes by the number of instances that you delete, so if you want to replace the nodes, you will then want to scale your cluster up to compensate). You can find the instance group name by running:

```
$ gcloud container clusters describe CLUSTER | grep instanceGroupManagers
```

> Is it safe to simply resize up and then delete the instance using gcloud compute, or is there some container-aware way to do this?

If you delete an instance, the managed instance group will replace it with a new one (so this will leave you with an extra node if you scale up by one, then delete the troublesome instance). If you were not concerned about the temporary loss of capacity, you could just delete the VM and let it get recreated.

Before removing an instance, you can run [kubectl drain](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_drain/) to remove the workload from the instance. This will result in a faster rescheduling of pods than if you simply deleting the instance and wait for the controllers to notice that it is gone.

Comment: As orderly as I had hoped for. Used `gcloud compute instance-groups managed resize` followed by `kubectl drain` and `gcloud compute instance-groups managed delete-instances`.

Comment: Is there a difference between `gcloud compute instance-groups managed resize` and `gcloud container clusters resize`?

Comment: Right now the later just finds the MIG URL for you and resizes the cluster (the GKE API itself doesn't currently expose a resize call).

Comment: for multi-zone clusters you need `instance-groups manage resize` because container clusters resize will affect all zones

Comment: Seems like a really incomplete or perhaps out of date answer. I want to replace a node specifically in a zone.

Answer (score 11):

We use multi-zone clusters now which means I needed a new way to get the instance group name. Current shell commands:

```
BAD_INSTANCE=[your node name from kubectl get nodes]

kubectl cordon $BAD_INSTANCE

kubectl drain $BAD_INSTANCE

gcloud compute instances describe --format='value[](metadata.items.created-by)' $BAD_INSTANCE

gcloud compute instance-groups managed delete-instances --instances=$BAD_INSTANCE --zone=[from describe output] [grp from describe output]
```

Comment: Edit: had `gcloud compute instance-groups managed resize --zone=[from describe output] --size=[desired size + 1] [grp from describe output]` prior to `delete-instances` here originally, but with current gcloud + k8s 1.7.12 that is unnecessary because `delete-instances` scales down by 1.

Comment: `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector spec.nodeName=$BAD_INSTANCE` is quite handy for assessing the damage node deletion will make :)

Answer (score 2):

You can recreate the bad node with the following command:

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed recreate-instances \
  --instances="$BAD_INSTANCE" \
  --zone="$ZONE" \
  "$INSTANCE_GROUP"
```

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

BAD_INSTANCE="$1"
FULL_ZONE=$(gcloud compute instances describe --format='value[](zone)' "$BAD_INSTANCE")
FULL_INSTANCE_GROUP=$(gcloud compute instances describe --format='value[](metadata.items.created-by)' "$BAD_INSTANCE")
ZONE=${FULL_ZONE##*/}
INSTANCE_GROUP=${FULL_INSTANCE_GROUP##*/}

echo "Recreating node '$BAD_INSTANCE' from zone '$ZONE' in instance group '$INSTANCE_GROUP'"
sleep 10

gcloud compute instance-groups managed recreate-instances \
  --instances="$BAD_INSTANCE" \
  --zone="$ZONE" \
  "$INSTANCE_GROUP"
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the previous answers, I created this shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

function gcp_delete_node_instance() {
  (
    local node="$1"
    set -e
    echo "Cordoning $node"
    kubectl cordon "$node"
    echo "Draining $node"
    kubectl drain "$node" --force --ignore-daemonsets
    zone="$(kubectl get node "$node" -o jsonpath='{.metadata.labels.topology\.gke\.io/zone}')"
    instance_group=$(gcloud compute instances describe --zone="$zone" --format='value[](metadata.items.created-by)' "$node")
    instance_group="${instance_group##*/}"
    echo "Deleting instance for node '$node' in zone '$zone' instance group '$instance_group'"
    gcloud compute instance-groups managed delete-instances --instances="$node" --zone="$zone" "$instance_group"
    echo "Deleting instance for node '$node' completed."
  )
}

gcp_delete_node_instance "$1"
```

GCP automatically creates a replacement node and adds it to the pool.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's guaranteed, but both times that I tried it, when scaling down, the autoscaler chooses drained nodes.  So to replace a node, I scaled up, drained the node and then scaled down.

Answer (score 0):

I use an autoscaling cluster.  Once I cordon a node in the UI, the system seems to move its pods to the others nodes, and then eventually remove the node.